# Jackson: How to deserialize interface with abstract base class?

Tags: java, json, jackson

I've been using Jackson for a while now, and there's one thing that has been bothering me. Maybe I'm doing it the wrong way. Let's assume we have the following classes:

```
@JsonSerialize(as = AbstractAnimal.class)  // these two lines...
@JsonDeserialize(as = AbstractAnimal.class) // ...are not doing what I want
public interface Animal { /* ... */ }

@JsonTypeInfo(use = Id.NAME, include = As.PROPERTY, property = "type")
@JsonSubTypes({
    @Type(value = Dog.class, name = "dog"),
    @Type(value = Cat.class, name = "cat")
})
public abstract class AbstractAnimal implements Animal { /* ... */ }

public class Dog extends AbstractAnimal { /* ... */ }
public class Cat extends AbstractAnimal { /* ... */ }
```

So there's an interface, accompanied by an abstract base class. The abstract base class lists the `JsonSubTypes`.

- If I try to deserialize a JSON string and ask for `AbstractAnimal.class`, then it works.
- However, deserializing a JSON string with type `Animal.class` does *not* work.

The reason why deserializing as `Animal.class` does not work is that `@JsonSerialize(as = AbstractAnimal.class)` attempts to really deserialize `Animal` as the **abstract base class**, which of course fails. What I would actually like to do here is to redirect Jackson's type inference mechanism to **recursively** check the annotations on `AbstractAnimal`, rather than using `AbstractAnimal` directly.

How is this done correctly in Jackson?

Comment: Hi I'm not sure but I think it's @JsonSerialize(contentAs= AbstractAnimal.class). See javadoc [contentAs](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.3.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/annotation/JsonSerialize.html#contentAs())

Comment: ... nope, unfortunately that doesn't do the trick. If you use `@JsonDeserialize(contentAs = AbstractAnimal.class)`, then for some weird reason Jackson will attempt to instantiate the `Animal` interface.